# Reading from an SSL input stream (Java)

Tags: java, server, client, client-server

I'm trying to write a simple protocol between a client and a server using an authenticated SSL connection and a number of control messages defined in the class bellow:

```
public class KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs {
    public static final String reqStr = "#REQ_KM";
    public static final String nonceStr = "#NONCE_END";
    public static final String ackStr = "#ACK_KM";
}
```

**client.java**

```
        // Connect to the server
        cSock = (SSLSocket) fact.createSocket(this.remoteHost, this.remotePort);
        // Create the streams to send out data as well as read data
        OutputStream out = cSock.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = cSock.getInputStream();
        // Generate client nonce
        byte[] clientNonceB = CryptographyUtils.generateRandomNumber();
        // Send the nonce and the request for a key from the server
        // First, send the keying material request to the server
        System.out.println("[I] SSL client written " + KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.reqStr);
        out.write(CryptographyUtils.toByteArray(KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.reqStr)); // <== Successfully written to the server
        // Next, send the generated nonce (by the client)
        System.out.println("[I] SSL client written nonce ");
        System.out.println(new String(clientNonceB, "UTF-8"));
        out.write(clientNonceB);
        // Finally, send the ending string
        System.out.println("[I] SSL client written " + KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.nonceStr);
        out.write(CryptographyUtils.toByteArray(KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.nonceStr));
        // Wait for the response from the server containing the key
        int ch = 0;
        String responseStr = "";
        while ((responseStr.contains(KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.ackStr) == false) && (responseStr.contains(KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.nonceStr) == false)) {
            ch = in.read();
            responseStr = responseStr + (char) ch;
            System.out.println("[I] SSL client read " + responseStr);
        }
        // Display read information from server
        System.out.println("[I] SSL client read " + responseStr);
        // Check if the server nonce contains the starting and end messages of the protocol

            String serverNonceStr = responseStr.substring(KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.ackStr.length(), responseStr.length() - KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.nonceStr.length());
            // Compute the key by xor-ing the client and server nonce and applying AES
            // on the resulting string
            clientKeyingMaterial = new SecretKeySpec(CryptographyUtils.xorStrings(clientNonceB, CryptographyUtils.toByteArray(serverNonceStr)), "AES");
            return clientKeyingMaterial;
```

**server.java**

```
        System.out.println("[I] SSL server listening");

        SSLSocket sslSock = (SSLSocket) sSock.accept();
        sslSock.startHandshake();

        System.out.println("[I] SSL server starting handshake");

        // Process if principal checks out
        if (isEndEntity(sslSock.getSession())) {
            // Create the streams to send out data as well as read data
            OutputStream out = sslSock.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in = sslSock.getInputStream();
            // Wait and read the client's nonce
            int ch = 0;
            String requestStr = "";
            while ((requestStr.contains(KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.reqStr) == false) && (requestStr.contains(KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.nonceStr) == false)) {
                ch = in.read();
                requestStr = requestStr + (char) ch;
                System.out.println("[I] SSL server received " + requestStr);
            }

            System.out.println("[I] SSL server received " + requestStr);
         }
```

The loop on the server side exits as soon as **KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.reqStr/#REQ_KM** is sent but does not wait for the actual nonce and ending message **KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.nonceStr/#NONCE_END**.

Why does the server side while loop exit before the last message is sent by the client?

Comment: You're  implementing a key exchange protocol *over* SSL? Why?

Comment: It's part of a larger project where backward-security of the exchanged data is required, but the session in which it has been exchanged in needs to be forward-secure. That key exchanged in the protocol is used to derive keys for arguments in an RPC calls pertinent to a varying number of servant objects. The key is then stored in order to allow for later decryption (in this case not directly as keys need to be derived from it (using HKMD)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because as soon as `requestStr` contains `KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.reqStr`, `requestStr.contains(KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.reqStr)` becomese `true`, so `requestStr.contains(KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.reqStr) == false` becomes `true == false`, which is `false`, so the entire test in the while loop becomes `false`, so execution drops out of the while loop.

There are a couple of ways to fix this, the easiest would be to have two while loops. The first just loops until `requestStr` is `KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.reqStr`, and the second that accumulates the nonce until it ends with `KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.nonceStr`. Something like this:

```
        String requestStr = "";
        while (!requestStr.equals(KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.reqStr)) {
            ch = in.read();
            requestStr = requestStr + (char) ch;
        }

        System.out.println("[I] SSL server received " + requestStr);

        String nonceStr = "";
        while (!requestStr.endsWith(KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.nonceStr)) {
            ch = in.read();
            nonceStr = nonceStr + (char) ch;
        }

        // Whack #NONCE_END from the end to get just the nonce.

        nonceStr = nonceStr.substring(0, nonceStr.length() - KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.nonceStr.length());

        System.out.println("[I] SSL server received " + nonceStr);
```

That's not tested but it should be close.

You could do it with a single while loop by keeping some sort of state indicator so you know when you're accumulating the `reqStr` and when you're accumulating the `nonceStr`, but I think splitting it like this is cleaner.

Comment: It actually becomes true as the requestStr does contain the protocol message at this point. It is false when it doesn't. I'm confused why the loop stops if the second part of the condition is not met.

Comment: @Sebi Sorry, by "first clause", I mean the `requestStr.contains(KeyExchangeProtcolMsgs.reqStr) == false` part. I'll edit my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: The reasoning behind the code is as follows: you have an initial message, a random nonce and an ending message. I want to read from the server side socket until the last protocol message is present.

Comment: @Sebi I edited my answer so hopefully it's clearer as to what's happening now. I'll edit it again to suggest a solution.

Comment: So what should be the best way of reading characters until both messages are present in the resulting string?

Comment: @Sebi Edited my answer to include a suggested fix.